# Declare global variable by user input from dialogframe

Tags: android, global-variables, android-dialogfragment

I want to ask something that make me very confused.

My problem is how to declare a global variable (String) by user input from dialogframe then save it into sqlite.

Thankyou for helping me..

Answer (score 0):

```
You can declare a global variable in your class that extend application,like this

    class MyAppApplication extends Application {

    private String mGlobalVarValue;

    public String getGlobalVarValue() {
        return mGlobalVarValue;
    }

    public void setGlobalVarValue(String str) {
        mGlobalVarValue = str;
    }
}
```

for getting value from that

```
  MyAppApplication mApp = ((MyAppApplication)getApplicationContext());
  String globalVarValue = mApp.getGlobalVarValue();
```